# Which word can be used for the person who is challenged (in a contest)?

Tags: antonyms

The words "challenge" and "challenger" are well-known, but is there such a term as "challengee" - as I read somewhere? In other words, what would be an appropriate term to describe the person challenged, for instance, to play a challenge match? Unsure whether to ask for the "antonym" of challenger.

Comment: [Google first](http://www.wordnik.com/words/challengee)

Comment: When the challenge involves trying to wrest an office or championship away from someone or something that currently holds it, your choices are numerous. In a political contest, the person being challenged is called the _officeholder_ or _incumbent_, and the challenger is called the _challenger_, _aspirant_, _upstart_, or _hopeful_. In a sports contest, the top-rated person or team being challenged may be called the _league_ (or _division_ or _bracket_) _leader_, the _current_ (or _reigning_ or _defending_) _champion_, or the _top dog_.

Answer (score 3):

However [Opponent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opponent) is in my opinion a better word for the other person in a contest

Comment: Aha thanks Mplungjan! Opponent sounds much better. Someone also  proposed Defender (not Defendant as in the legal context). Defender, as opposed to challenger, implies defending a ranking position.

Answer (score 2):

Challenger and Challenged (sometimes "the challenged")are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I asked because I used the word in a bilingual form for my tennis club. In my language (Afrikaans) we have a single word for both, but in English its a bit lenghty to write "the challenged" (person), or "Name of the challenged player". Better then to qualify it as "challenged player" since "challenged person" has the euphemistic connotation of disability.

Comment: 'Challengee' has 33 000 Google hits, though probably some are for strange applications. If it's a students' tennis club, the members would probably go happily with 'challengee'; if it has a rather more sedate membership, the word-or-is-it? is best avoided.

Comment: Now that we know you are talking about a tennis challenge ladder format, just call them players. See here for an example - http://www.charlotte.usta.com/Adult_Challenge_Ladders/challeng_ladder_rules/ The format is normally structured such that there is no reason to distinguish between the two once a challenge has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The term generally used in boxing (which would be a good fit for what you want) is "defending champion."

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **the one challenged**, which emphasises the binary relation with the challenger. It has some good results in Google books, [among which](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HFyeYZfD410C&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22the+one+challenged%22&source=bl&ots=SrebJysAKj&sig=b_6730U1ghn3z8_W7V7pjErr4Tc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20one%20challenged%22&f=false) :

> The public scrutinizes the reaction of the one challenged.

(Paul in the Greco-Roman World: A Handbook edited by J. Paul Sampley)

Answer (score 0):

When someone is challenging another person to perform a dare, or demonstration of courage, one might call the person who is challenging the "darer" and the one who is dared as the "challenged".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

"defender" can be used in sporting context.
When X challenges Y, then Y has to defend himself to win the challenge.

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system is almost certain to flag it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *defender* (linked to the source), and perhaps an example sentence. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)